# Python: Create dataframe from a list where each new row starts at a specific list index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list where the number of items between a 'SUMMARY' element and the next one is not fixed

```
list = ['SUMMARY - Dec 2013', 'Person1', 'None', 'None', '10', 'SUMMARY - Dec 2013', 'Person2', '20', 'SUMMARY - Jan 2014', 'Person3', 'None']
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to **transform the list to a dataframe where each row starts with a 'SUMMARY' element**.

I've used

```
match = []
match.append([n for n, l in enumerate(list) if l.startswith('SUMMARY')])
```

with output `[[0, 5, 8]]` to get the indexes of the items that contain 'SUMMARY', and I would like each row of my dataframe to start with the corresponding items whose indexes are included in `match`. In this case, match has 3 elements, so I would like my dataframe to have 3 rows and the following structure:

```
'SUMMARY - Dec 2013', 'Person1', 'None', 'None', '10'
'SUMMARY - Dec 2013', 'Person2', '20',   NA,    NA
'SUMMARY - Jan 2014', 'Person3', 'None', NA,    NA
```

Basically, when the number of items for a specific row is smaller than the number of max columns, the rest gets filled with NA/NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the sample data. It is easier to approach this if you start with a single Series. You can group rows of data based on whether "Summary" is present and then use this to aggregate and re-explode your data across columns.

```
s = pd.Series(your_list)
pd.DataFrame(s.groupby(s.str.contains('summary', case=False).cumsum())
              .agg(list)
              .tolist())                                                   

                    0        1     2     3     4
0  SUMMARY - Dec 2013  Person1  None  None    10
1  SUMMARY - Dec 2013  Person2    20  None  None
2  SUMMARY - Jan 2014  Person3  None  None  None
```

---

Thanks @Shubham Sharma for the suggestion of iterating over groups:

```
pd.DataFrame([g.tolist() for k, g in s.groupby(
    s.str.contains('summary', case=False).cumsum())])

                    0        1     2     3     4
0  SUMMARY - Dec 2013  Person1  None  None    10
1  SUMMARY - Dec 2013  Person2    20  None  None
2  SUMMARY - Jan 2014  Person3  None  None  None
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([grp.tolist() for k, grp in s.groupby(s.str.contains('summary', case=False).cumsum())` might be faster, what do you think?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma that would work as well, why not post an answer?